# java.lang.RuntimeException with Facebook Login example

Tags: java, android, facebook, multithreading, android-asynctask

I'm following the [Facebook guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.0) to make a login app for Android. After:

1. Install Facebook app (unnecessary) on the virtual device
2. Import Facebook SDK into Android Studio as Module
3. Import the previous module into the project and
4. Modify the code as the guide says

the project compiles. But when I run the machine and try to open the application it crash showing:

> Unfortunately, the application has stopped.

I couldn't find a solution after read similar posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7724341/1505348) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8946228/1505348).

I'm using Android 0.5.8, Oracle JDK 7 and the API 16 as *target*, *min* and *max*.

The main files are [`activity_main.xml`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7548494/), [`MainActivity.java`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7548497/) and [`MainFragment.java`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7548504/).

Here is the latest *logcat* output:

```
05-30 03:15:54.127      647-664/com.jdk8.minifacebookloginapp.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:781)
            at com.facebook.internal.Utility.queryAppSettings(Utility.java:372)
            at com.facebook.widget.LoginButton$1.doInBackground(LoginButton.java:676)
            at com.facebook.widget.LoginButton$1.doInBackground(LoginButton.java:673)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The problem is not coming from your code but from the facebook SDK.  You can tell by looking at the top of the NullPointerException

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:781)
        at com.facebook.internal.Utility.queryAppSettings(Utility.java:372)
```

The error last two triggering lines are from the facebook sdk (com.facebook.internal) and your java.util package neither of which are from your code.

To fix this, you need to finish the setup in the facebook's [getting started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) tutorial for android where you register your app after generating an android key hash.  After you've done that, open your AndroidManifest.xml and add the **meta-data line**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Then add your app_id into the strings.xml file (found from the settings page in [your facebook developer account](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)
The app id is on your facebook developer account.

Once you've done this it should compile

Comment: You're right. But I'm still missing something. The application launch, but it crash when I click on the "Login" button. It gives [this error](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7605022/), but I think that it is another issue (I should create another question). Is this related?

Comment: I solved the previous error with procedure mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13509113/1505348) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2169294/1505348).

Comment: This was my problem, and this fixed it. :)

Comment: this is perfect! why is this not ever mentioned on the facebook developer pages?

Comment: @Todd Anderson can you provide sample application for facebook button widget and login

Comment: The facebook SDK should at least add a null check to show a clear exception of what went wrong in this case

Answer (score 3):

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

was missing in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
```

at right place inside the application not inside the activity